# How to log Virtualbox VRDP logins?

Tags: logging, virtualbox, remote-desktop, vnc

I am running multiple headless VMs on my ubuntu VPS. I have configured VNC on VRDP ports for these VMs. How do I log every VNC session ? Can't find anything on VM Docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
I run it with administrative user, UAC is disabled.

Is this error normal: Could not resolve import 'VRDPAuth2'. Error code: VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND

00:10:40.057 VRDP: Client seems to be MSFT. 00:10:40.057 VRDP: Logon: BORIS-HAMANOV (192.168.180.111) build 6002. User: [inka] Domain: [] Screen: 0 00:10:40.058 VRDPAUTH: User: [inka]. Domain: []. Authentication type: [External] 00:10:40.059 VRDPAUTH: ConsoleVRDPServer::Authenticate: loading external authentication library 'VRDPAuth' 00:10:40.088 VRDPAUTH: Could not resolve import 'VRDPAuth2'. Error code: VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND 00:10:40.100 VRDPAUTH: Using entry point 'VRDPAuth'. 00:10:40.101 VRDPAUTH: external authentication module returned 'access denied' 00:10:40.101 VRDPAUTH: Access denied. 00:10:40.101 VRDP: Connection closed:
```

Comment: Can you share the reference/source document for the above snippet ?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

there is reference for the above snippet.

Comment: Can't find anything about logging VRDP sessions in above link.

Comment: you can research about that because i am not more knlowledge about that